# Firebase path or parent on a flutter firebase database event (onValue, onChildChanged)

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dart, flutter

I am trying to either get the path or parent when a listener is triggered
for instance.

```
// Setting Listener on friends info CHANGE

  database.reference().child('user/$k/info').onChildChanged.listen((event){
    print('Triggered Listener on -- CHANGED -- friend info');

    // I want to get the variable k here or the parent value of info when the 
        // listener is triggered

  }),
```

Answer (score 0):

My co-worker helped me understand closures a bit better. Because I was calling the listen function within a forEach I could access the variable $k when the listener triggered.

````
    var values = new Map<String, dynamic>.from(snapshot.value);
    values.forEach((k, v) =>
    {
      // k represents each friend's uid pulled from the user's friend list
      // Settings Listener on friends info CHANGE
      database.reference().child('user/$k/info').onChildChanged.listen((event){
        print('$k'); // <- The user ID I was looking for
        print('Triggered Listener on -- CHANGED -- friend info');
        print('info that changed: ${event.snapshot.key}: ${event.snapshot.value}');
      }),```
````